# limit min width of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the ff css properties:

```
.header {

width: 100%;

background-color: #1cb14d;

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
border-bottom: none;
z-index: 999;

font-family:'Segoe UI Light';
color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">

        <div class="section_container">
            <div class="col span_1_of_12">
                //something here
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_12">
                //something here
            </div>
            <div class="col span_7_of_12">
                //something here
            </div>
            <div class="col span_3_of_12">
                //something here
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want to limit the min-width of it but it doesn't seem to work. I need to set the min-width to prevent the div from covering other contents when browser is size is adjusted. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: `max-width` perhaps?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? Are you trying to enforce a minimum width or a maximum width? Covering unwanted elements on the page usually suggests the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If the .header needs to have a min-width, you can just add it:

`.header { width: 100%;
           min-width: 200px; }`

Otherwise, if you want the section_container to have a min-width:

`.section_container { min-width: 200px; }`

This will override/add the frameworks default min-width if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're anchoring the element to the left and right boundry of the viewport with these directives, which supersede `min-width` and `min-height`:

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Remove them and then add a `min-width` or a `max-width` directive, depending on the effect you're looking for.